# hibernate: migration to 4.2 (from 3.6.10) breaks bag collections

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have a one-directional many-to-many mapping between a Father object and a Child object.
The mapping is configured using an hbm.xml file:

```
    <bag name="children" table="FATHERS_CHILDREN" cascade="none" >
        <key column="FATHER_ID" not-null="true" update="false" foreign-key="FATHERS_CHILDREN__FATHER_FK"/>
        <many-to-many class="Child" column="CHILD_ID" foreign-key="FATHERS_CHILDREN__CHILD_FK"/>
    </bag>
```

So practically, the Father has a collection of Child.
We've encountered the following issue after migrating from hiberante 3.6.10 to 4.2.21:
When changing the Father's children collection, hibernate does NOT issue a delete statement to delete rows from the FATHERS_CHILDREN table.
Thus, if we had a Father object with three children (child1, child2, child3) and then we changed the children collection to only contain child1 (by executing `Father.children.clear()` and `Father.children.add(child1)`), after the transaction is committed, the Father's collection will have 4 children (child1 will be preset twice in the children collection).

Needless to say, this worked well with hibernate 3.6.10 and hibernate did issue a delete statement to remove rows from the mapping table (FATHER_CHILDREN).

**UPDATE**
Some needed information:
The Father object is detached and to actually update it we execute: `getSession().update(getSession().merge(Father))`
Additionally, it seems that this scenario present itself only when using TestNG groups dependencies.

Any Thoughts ?